# Remove unwanted text string with strange hex character?

Tags: string, text, hex, character

I have a program that reads in hex strings, and returns text based on the parameters of the string. A hex string goes as follows:

```
A : B : C
```

A - Length of B

B - Name of interface

C - Unimportant

so for example;

```
0465746830010000 = 
04 : 65746830 : 010000 =
4 : eth0 : __________
```

Now, I want to process the hex strings so that if there is a character that isn't in the alphabet, 0-9, or '-' , it lets me know somehow.

Such as here :

```
0266010000
02 : 6601 : _______
2 : f[unreadable] : _______
```

Any ideas on how would I process this so that it lets me know if any of the characters outside of these parameters arise?

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Oops. I am using Python

Comment: I don't know Python well aside from the fact that it does support regular expressions: this is the approach you should take.

Answer (score 0):

A quick regex can do that, for instance in java:

```
myString.matches([0-9a-fA-F]*)
```

will return `true` if the entire string consists of hex digits, and will return `false` if there are other characters.

Also, why would you want to accept the `-` character?  These strings should (if properly designed) contain the *unsigned* representations of the numbers.  If they are out of your control, then I guess you just gotta deal with it, but still.